# Will a packet with an invalid ACK number be dropped by the receiving side?

Tags: networking, tcp

I have read that if a packet in TCP does not have a valid sequence number, then the packet will be dropped by the receiving side.

But what if the packet have a valid sequence number but have an invalid ACK number, will the packet also be dropped by the receiving side?

Answer (score 1):

There's really no such thing as an "invalid" acknowledgement number.  If you mean that the number doesn't fall within the window (the advertised memory buffer of the host), that's a different question.

If the ACK isn't within the window, the host will respond with a reset to indicate that it has no notion of there being a connection with these "keys", where the keys are source, destination, source port, destination port, sequence numbers.

Comment: I have found this PDF file: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Book/book_sample_tcp.pdf, which says that only the sequence number must be valid (it doesn't say anything about the ACK number): *"for the packet to be accepted, one more critical condition needs to be satisfied. It is the TCP sequence number"*, so is the information in this PDF file wrong?

Comment: That isn't completely correct.  The acknowledgement number *must* be in the window if the ACK bit is set, by definition.  If it isn't and everything else is correct, it desynchronizes the session.  The acknowledgement number is telling the receiver where the sender believes that it is in the stream.  As the author/instructor of this (https://www.sans.org/course/intrusion-detection-in-depth) I have some practicalknowledge here. :)

Comment: What if the packet has an invalid sequence number, will the connection be terminated also in the same way that it does if the packet has an invalid ACK number (because I have read in other websites that if a packet has an invalid sequence number, then the packet will only be dropped)?

Comment: Don't think of it as "invalid".  Any 32 bit number is "valid."  It's whether or not it fits into the session.  Otherwise, yes, assuming the ports and IPs are correct, it will be dropped.  If it's in the window, however, it will again desynchronize the session.  If such a packet were spoofed, for example, the session cannot resynchronize and it will likely turn into an ack storm, finally getting torn down.